# Not getting the input values when printing vector of pairs

Tags: c++

I want to add a pair to a vector of pairs.
When I print the vector elements, I don't get the integers I input.
Please help.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #include<utility>
    using namespace std;


     int main()
     {
        vector<vector<unsigned long int> >matrix;
        vector<pair<int,int> >pmat;
        int L;
            cin>>L;
        int n1, n2;
        pmat.resize(L);
        for(int k = 0; k<L; k++)
        {
             cin>>n1>>n2;
             pair<int,int> p = make_pair(n1,n2);
             cout<<p.first<<p.second<<endl;
             pmat.push_back(p);
        }
        for(int k = 0; k<L; k++)
        {
           cout<<pmat[k].first<<','<<pmat[k].second<<' ';
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: `pmat.resize(L)` -> `pmat.reserve(L)`. You're first resizing then push_backing. Do only one of these.

Comment: yep. thats its. resize and assign, OR pushback. not resize+pushback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**:
Delete this line:

```
pmat.resize(L);
```

You don't need to resize it in the first place as you do `push_back()` when adding afterwards.

---

**Method 2**: 
Change the following line

```
pmat.push_back(p);
```

to

```
pmat[k] = p;
```

You can do `resize()` in the first place, but after this, you should not use `push_back()` when adding, just use `pmat[k] = p`.

---

**PS**: you should not mix these two ways up. Always use one of them consistently.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `pmat.resize(L)` and L times `pmat.push_back(...)`, you're ending up having stored 2 * L entries in your vector. However you're printing just the first half, index 0 to L - 1. The values you want are stored from index L to 2 * L - 1.

Just change `pmat.resize(L)` to `pmat.reserve(L)`.

Alternatively, you can use the `resize(L)`, but to end up with `L` entries, you need to store each input pair to `pmat[k]`, hence you write `pmat[k] = p;`.

As a rule of thumb, I recommend using the `reserve` + `push_back` approach if you know how many elements you're going to add. The reason is, that `resize` initializes the elements, while reserving just asserts that there will be enough space and no reallocation will be necessary with any following push_back.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add more pairs after you allocated them. You can now directly access them.
Just use `pmat[k] = p;` instead of `pmat.push_back(p);`

Answer (score 0):

If you print the size of the vector after reading the values, you will notice a small problem with your program:

```
./test                                                                                                                                                               
2 
1 2
12
3 4
34
Size of the vector: 4
0,0 0,0
```

Huh? Even though I only entered 2 pairs, the size of the vector is 4. How did this happen?

If you look at the [documentation for resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize), it says

> Resizes the container to contain count elements.

So even before you read any values, your vector will already contain 2 elements! Those will be default-constructed and therefore be 0. When you then `push_pack` the elements you read in, those will land at the indices 2 and 3 in the vector, so the end vector has twice as much elements as you wanted (4 in this case). You only print out the first half, which are the zero values.

The solution is to use [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) instead of resize, which doesn't create the elements but only reserves space for them, or just delete the call to resize. Using reserve is more efficient though, because then the vector will only need to allocate memory once.

Answer (score 0):

**pmat.resize(L);**

if vector in empty its going to initialize a vector pmat with size L then assign default values to vector so now pmat size is L with default values

```
for(int k = 0; k<L; k++)
        {
             cin>>n1>>n2;
             pair<int,int> p = make_pair(n1,n2);
             cout<<p.first<<p.second<<endl;
             pmat.push_back(p);
        }
```

then u r pushing values to pmat L times so the final size is **2*L**

```
for(int k = 0; k<L; k++)
        {
           cout<<pmat[k].first<<','<<pmat[k].second<<' ';
        }
```

here u r going to read from 0 to L-1 , it contains default values you can see your values from L-1 to 2L-1.
so finally what i want say is use reserve instead of resize 
                              or
pmat.resize(L); comment this line